# WKWebView get rid of native player

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I want to block native player of WKWebView forever.
These lines dont work in some cases:

```
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
```